# Proper way to test for "x" or "y" in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I wanted to demonstrate a simple if statement in Python (3.7).
I ended up writing a simple code (v1_alt.1).

v1_alt.1 works as expected and I feel it demonstrate easily how an if statement may work. And I also wanted to evaluate ex. 'dark green' as True.

But I felt it should have been written somehow different. So I ended up testing different code. I ended up with different approaches to demonstrate what is working and not. But I have problem understand it and why.

```
### v1
color = input("v1 - What is my favourite color? ") # ex. dark green

# alt.1 - Working code. Accept ex. 'dark green'.
if "red" in color or "green" in color:
    print(f"You entered {color}. That is is one of my favourite colors! "
          "(v1_alt.1)")

# alt.2 - Not working code. Will always evaluate True (Why?)
if "red" or "green" in color:
    print(f"You entered {color}. That is is one of my favourite colors! "
          "(v1_alt.2)")

# alt.3 - Not working code. Will always evaluate Red True, but not Green (Why?)
if ("red" or "green") in color:
    print(f"You entered {color}. That is is one of my favourite colors! "
          "(v1_alt.3)")

# alt.4 - Not working code. Will always evaluate True (Why)
if ("red" or "green" in color):
    print(f"You entered {color}. That is is one of my favourite colors! "
          "(v1_alt.4)")

# alt. 5 - Working code, but I want to accept ex. 'dark green'
if color in {"red", "green"}:
    print(f"You entered {color}. That is is one of my favourite colors! "
          "(v1_alt.5)")


### v2
fav_colors = ("red", "green")
color = input("v2 - What is my favourite color? ") # ex: dark green

for c in fav_colors:
    if c in color:
        print(f"You entered {color}. That is correct! "
          f"{c} is one of my favourite colors "
          "(v2_alt.1)")

if [c for c in fav_colors if c in color]:
    print(f"You entered {color}. That is correct! "
          f"{c} is one of my favourite colors "
          "(v2_alt.2)")
```

Why will v1_alt.2 and v1_alt.4 always evaluate as True?

Why will a 'red' answer, but not a 'green' answer, in v1_alt.3 evaluate True?

What is the best way to write v1_alt.1? I can write a v2 code, but I want to keep it simple for tutorial purpose.

Comment: I would do `any(option in colour for option in ("red", "green")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python an object `x` is called truthy if `bool(x) is True`, i.e. the object is equivalent to `True` in a boolean context.

```
# alt.2 - Not working code. Will always evaluate True (Why?)
if "red" or "green" in color:
```

That expression is evaluated as `"red" or ("green" in color)`. Since `"red"` is truthy, so is the expression (the second part is not even evaluated).

```
# alt.3 - Not working code. Will always evaluate Red True, but not Green (Why?)
if ("red" or "green") in color:
```

The expression in parentheses evaluates to `"red"`, because in Python `or` and `and` return their arguments. `or` returns either the first argument, if it is truthy, or the second argument in any other case. So, the entire statement can be reduced to `if 'red' in color: ...`

Your fourth example is equivalent to the second one: those parentheses change nothing.

```
# alt. 5 - Working code, but I want to accept ex. 'dark green'
if color in {"red", "green"}
```

Then nothing stops you from adding the colour to that set: `{"red", "green", "dark green"}`.

> What is the best way to write v1_alt.1

There are hardly any "best ways", as these things tend to be a matter of taste. That being said, if you have a fixed set of colours, I'd use a tuple or a set as in your "alt 5" example. If you have a fixed set of base colours and the modifiers are always expected to be in the beginning (as in "dark green") and space-separated, you can split incomming strings: `if color.split()[-1] in base_colors`, where `base_colors` is a set/tuple/list/(any searchable data structure) of base colours. If your task demands complicated logic, you'd be far better off with a dedicated function:

```
def validate_color(base_colors, color):
    """
    Validate a color.
    """
    return color.split()[-1] in base_colors


if validate_color(base_colors, color):
    ...
```

A function encapsulates implementation details that would otherwise "pollute" your main execution graph. Moreover, it can be safely modified without ever touching the other parts (as long as you keep it pure).

Comment: This is a great answer. The one thing I'd quibble with is where, in the first prose paragraph, you say "`"red" is always `True`" (and something similar later on that's similar when discussing `and` and `or`). That's not really correct, as you can see evaluating `"red" == True`. A more accurate thing to say is that `"red"` is "truthy" (meaning that `bool("red") == True`). It's useful to use the terms "truthy" and "falsey" to describe non-`bool` objects in Boolean contexts, without confusing them with Python's actual `bool` objects `True` and `False`.

Comment: @Blckknght or just say "`bool("red")` is always True" ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I can cleary see the problems with alt. 2 -> alt. 4 now when you explained it. Then I know I will stick with alt. 1 for now. I was curious  if there was an even easier way to do it (ex. Python2 vs Python3 syntax)- The example is meant to explain if/else/or/and to kids. We will progress with other ways to do it as we move along.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, that's a fine correction; I've hesitated on the issues myself, because Python docs tend to use "true" and "false" without explicit differentiation from `True` and `False`.

Comment: @Mr.Anderson As I've already mentioned, the more conventional way of doing it is either your `alt. 5` example or a dedicated function. Py2 and Py3 are similar in this regard. If you are targeting kids, you can use a fixed set of colours without introducing additional logic to handle compound colours. Or you can actually explain what function/method calls are. The choice largely depends on your end-goals and the audience.