# Accepting multiple variations of input from user - Python

Tags: python-3.x, input, ascii, calculator

So I'm building an ASCII based calculator and I want to account for user variation in inputs (such accepting both "Quit" and "quit" and "QUIT" and "q" and "Q" in an if/else sequence). Heres what I kind of came up with but there's probably a better way of going about it because it will only take the first input type listed.

```
elif input == ("j" or "J" or "linear" or "Linear" or "quadratic" or "Quadratic" or "linear and 
quadratic" or "Linear and Quadratic" or "Linear and quadratic" or "linear and quadratic" or "LINEAR 
AND QUADRATIC"):
```

In this case, the sequence will only accept "j" and throw up my else error message if any of the other input variations are used. Any thoughts on a better way to do this? I use python 3 btw.

Comment: That entire line of code is equivalent to `elif input == "j": `. You might want to consider this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621705/proper-way-to-test-for-x-or-y-in-a-string/54621800#54621800

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest passing expected/desired values to some sort of function:

```
def get_input(message, desired_values, is_int=False):
    user_input = input(message)
    if user_input in desired_values:
        return user_input if not is_int else int(user_input)
    else:
        return get_input("Wrong input, possible inputs: {}: ".format(
            ", ".join(desired_values)), desired_values, is_int)

input = get_input("type", ['v1', 'v2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```py
quit = {"q", "quit", ...}
if input in quit:
    # actually quit
```

Also it would probably be easier to convert your input to lowercase (using `input.lower() in quit`), so you don't need to write all the variants (such as "quit", "Quit", "QUIT"... bit it will accept "qUiT" also if that is not a problem).

Comment: That would actually simplify a lot of the menus by setting it to lower case.